# Chart.JS Plugin causing errors when used twice

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I have written a very simple plugin for colouring negative values in bar charts;

```
var ColourNegatives = {
     beforeDraw: function(c) {
     var data = c.data.datasets[0].data;
     for (let i in data) {
        let bar = c.data.datasets[0]._meta['0'].data[i]._model;
        if (data[i] > 0) {
           bar.backgroundColor = '#337AB7';
        } else bar.backgroundColor = '#B73434';
     }
  }
  };
```

This works without issue when including it as a plugin for a single bar chart.

When I have 2 charts on the same page, the second chart fails to generate and the console shows 
**TypeError: c.data.datasets[0]._meta[0] is undefined**

The issue is the meta[0] part.  If I have two functions (one for each table) and have one with meta[0] and the other with meta[1], everything works.

Does anyone know how I can get the Meta number to match the chart number instead of having a separate plugin for each chart?  Eventually, there may be 10+ charts on the page that all need this colouring scheme

I've tried various things like a for loop;

```
var x;
for (x= 0; x < 5; x++) {
   /* Plugin Code */
    }
```

but this doesn't work.

Comment: And what does `c.data.datasets[0]._meta` contain?

Comment: I resolved this issue by using a new var with identical code and just called that on the second chart.